# Add new components to component tree during PreRenderView event of postback

Tags: jsf-2, components, seam3

Is it possible to create new `UIComponent`s and add it to component tree during the `PreRenderView` event of a postback? If so, how can I do it using `public void onPreRenderEvent(@Observes PreRenderViewEvent e)` in Seam 3?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I have been working with both the Mojarra team and the MyFaces team to establish the 'accepted' way of doing this. I have blogged their conclusions here:

http://blog.kennardconsulting.com/2010/10/safely-manipulating-component-tree-with.html

The JSF EG are also looking at formalizing this in their spec:

http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-1007